# dailyLimitExceededUnreg from Fusion Tables API

Tags: google-api, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to do a simple tables call

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/tables/.......
```

but no matter what I do I can't get beyond

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

I have tried making the request both with and without a browser key.
I have tried with both "Public on the web" and "Anyone with the link".
The "Allow Downloads" flag is set.
I'm not sure what else has to be set up?

Edit:

The full URL is

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/tables/<table id>&key=<browser key>
```

I've also tried a SELECT, with the same result.

Comment: That error message seems pretty clear to me.  You need to some sort of an authenticated request.

Comment: Where are you making the request from? Your computer?  Your server?  A shared server at a hosting company?

Comment: The syntax in [your URL is incorrect](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/getting_started#browserURL).  The example in the referenced documentation [works for me](https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/tables/1KxVV0wQXhxhMScSDuqr-0Ebf0YEt4m4xzVplKd4/columns?key=AIzaSyAm9yWCV7JPCTHCJut8whOjARd7pwROFDQ)

Comment: The syntax in the URL is not incorrect.

Comment: You have "&" where there should be a "?" (at least in your posted question).

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right, because in this case the table ID is part of the URL, not a parameter to it. Now if you could write that as an answer so you get credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax in [your URL is incorrect](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/getting_started#browserURL). The example in the referenced documentation [works for me](https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/tables/1KxVV0wQXhxhMScSDuqr-0Ebf0YEt4m4xzVplKd4/columns?key=AIzaSyAm9yWCV7JPCTHCJut8whOjARd7pwROFDQ)

Answer (score 0):

You need an API key, you can read more about it here https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#APIKey

Comment: You are correct, and like I said above "I have tried making the request both with and without a browser key". Can you tell me why the key didn't work?

Comment: Can you post the full url you used?

Comment: Can't post URL here, see original question section.